# session not working when communicating with localhost

Tags: php, session, http-headers

If I navigate to 'sub.domain.com/session_test.php' in browser, the session are saved and work fine. I can see all the sessions on page refresh.

However, if I make an http post request from javascript in localhost to the same URL, the sessions are not being saved because I dont get any data(data in the "if" statement) back.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
session_start();


if(isset($_SESSION['u'])){  

var_dump(ini_get('session.save_path'));
var_dump(ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'));
var_dump(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'));
echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, TRUE) . '</pre>';
die();

}

$_SESSION['u'] = "34343gf"; 
die('end');
```

Comment: Sessions use cookies, and cookies are associated with specific domains.

Comment: Sessions are stored on the server, not on the browser. Only the identifier `session_id` is stored through a cookie on the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP Session variable is server side. Cookies only store the session id in order to retrieve the correct session information.

Anyway, assuming:

**`sub.domain.com/session_test.php` is an alias to `localhost/session_test.php` (they point to the same file)?**

You can't read cookies from one domain in another domain, even if they resolve to the same server. However, there are ways to corcumvent this. One way is to pass the cookie session id as a GET param, although this is not very safe.

Another way is to store the session ID locally (in a text file, or the database) and retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code with a pair of files named index.php and index2.php.
The session is working. (Windows7, Wamp2.5, Apache2.22, php5.4)

I think you have no rights into your /tmp folder where the session is.
Try to put a file inside it with php function `file_put_contents( ini_get('session.save_path')."/test-file.txt", 'Test file is OK');`.

Your code is OK.